# Can a link be disabled after ondblclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two links: one link makes my text red, the other makes my text blue. After I click one link, I want to disable both links.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to both, and if fired, remove the event handler for both. When one is clicked, both will be disabled:

```
$('#red, #blue').on('click', function() {
    $('#red, #blue').off('click');
    //$('#red, #blue').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Not sure what you mean by "disabled", or what doubleclicks has to do with it, but the concept is the same either way?

Comment: By disabled, I mean that when you click on it, it won't do anything. Do links have a property that does that?